# What is the purpose of Skype Web tagging by Skype id?

Tags: skype-for-web

When you use Skype Web and you press symbol `@`, you get a list of all people who are in the Skype group. You can tag one of them in order to address to him/her. And this is what we all do on forums and in the group chat.

Is there anything more to this? I did not notice that my tagging informs person that I had tagged him? It does not get a notification, or email or at least "Group blink" like I had expected.

I am not sure if I am using it wrongly or this is it (another Skype useless feature).